# What, and how does the stack pointer of a Process Control Block point to?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, stack, system-calls

The following text describes the role of the stack pointers in a Processor State Information of a Process Control Block.

It is on Table 3.5 of Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles, 9e.

```
Stack Pointers 

Each process has one or more last-in-first-out (LIFO) system stacks associated with it. 
A stack is used to store parameters and calling addresses for procedure and system calls. 
The stack pointer points to the top of the stack.
```

Is the stack the kernel stack?

I haven't heard that the user stack stores the calling addresses for procedure calls and system calls. It is the role of kernel stack.

The following text describes the esp register that is the CPU stack pointer, in UnderStanding The Linux Kernel 3e.

```
The esp register is the CPU stack pointer, which is used to address the stack’s top location. 
On 80×86 systems, the stack starts at the end and grows toward the beginning of the memory area. 
Right after switching from User Mode to Kernel Mode, the kernel stack of a process is always empty, 
and therefore the esp register points to the byte immediately following the stack.
```

That is, the kernel stack of a process is initially empty.

So, does the kernel copy the part of kernel Page Table to the kernel stack of the process When the process needs master a calling address?.

I'm not sure about this part. Also, I don't know if my understanding is correct overall.

Answer (score 0):

**Is the stack the kernel stack?**
No there are 2 types of stacks maintained by the OS. One is the user stack and another is the kernel stack. The difference between those are the privileged vs unprivileged mode.
In privileged mode, you can run some instructions which otherwise can't be run. This is required to maintain the security in OS. OS is the king and it can do few things which other processes can't do.
**The following text describes the esp register...**
What is happening here is that, the process calls for some system call. Now the process itself can't execute the system call, that is the job of the OS. now how does OS execute it? 
It takes the control of the system. But OS is also a process. It needs its own memory and resources. So it is going to put some values in the memory. That is where ESP will be used as it is used to point to the start of the stack. But there is a security question.
If I use the "normal" memory, some rogue process can modify it. So OS plays the king again. It has its "restricted" space in memory which only it can use. That is done by the help of the hardware.
Initially it will be empty because OS will stuff some values in it later. And here comes your last question. How does it go back to the original process?
OS does push some registers values in its "restricted" stack space. So that it can use registers to run its own code and later before returning the control to the original process, it does push saved values back to those registers. It has its own instruction to do so which only the OS can run (I think it is iret but you can search for it yourself).
So in short it is the switching between the "god" mode and "peasant" mode. You might want to read more about those privilage levels in OS.